# Error while merging split part of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
test = [(0,1,2),(9,0,1),(0,1,3),(0,1,8)]
test=np.array(test)
test = np.array_split(test, 4)
t_0 = test[:0]
t_1 = test[0]
new_test= t_0+test[1:]
print(new_test)
```

It is giving me following answer : `[array([[9, 0, 1]]), array([[0, 1, 3]]), array([[0, 1, 8]])]`

Whereas I am aiming for `[(9,0,1),(0,1,3),(0,1,8)]` if I select the first set from test.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to split numpy array to 4 parts and take one part at a time,and merge the other three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up lists and arrays.  Pay attention to what you get at each stage:

Start with a list of tuples:

```
In [126]: test = [(0,1,2),(9,0,1),(0,1,3),(0,1,8)]
```

Make a 2d array:

```
In [127]: arr = np.array(test)                                                  
In [128]: arr                                                                   
Out[128]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [9, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 8]])
```

Split into a list - one 'row' per element, but each is a 2d array.  Question, will the split number always be this size?

```
In [129]: alist = np.array_split(arr, arr.shape[0])                             
In [130]: alist                                                                 
Out[130]: 
[array([[0, 1, 2]]),
 array([[9, 0, 1]]),
 array([[0, 1, 3]]),
 array([[0, 1, 8]])]
```

Sublists:

```
In [131]: alist[:0]                                                             
Out[131]: []
In [132]: alist[1:]                                                             
Out[132]: [array([[9, 0, 1]]), array([[0, 1, 3]]), array([[0, 1, 8]])]
```

List join:

```
In [133]: alist[:0] + alist[1:]                                                 
Out[133]: [array([[9, 0, 1]]), array([[0, 1, 3]]), array([[0, 1, 8]])]
```

Looks like what you want is a list of tuples, like what you started with:

```
In [134]: test[:0] + test[1:]                                                   
Out[134]: [(9, 0, 1), (0, 1, 3), (0, 1, 8)]
```

You could recreate a 2d array, by applying `concatenate` to the joined lists of arrays:

```
In [135]: np.concatenate(alist[:0] + alist[1:])                                 
Out[135]: 
array([[9, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 8]])
In [136]: np.concatenate(alist[:1] + alist[2:])                                 
Out[136]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [0, 1, 8]])
In [137]: np.concatenate(alist[:2] + alist[3:])                                 
Out[137]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [9, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 8]])
```

But note that you could just as easily get any of these arrays with indexing:

```
In [138]: arr[[0,1,3],:]                                                        
Out[138]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [9, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 8]])
```

And with the `r_` helper you could construct the indices from ranges:

```
In [139]: np.r_[:2, 3:4]                                                        
Out[139]: array([0, 1, 3])
In [140]: arr[np.r_[:2, 3:4],:]                                                 
Out[140]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [9, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 8]])
```

You could also do the join after indexing:

```
In [141]: np.concatenate([arr[:2,:], arr[3:,:]], axis=0)                        
Out[141]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [9, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 8]])
```

`+` is define for lists a a join operator.  For arrays it is addition.  `concatenate` (along with various `stack` variants) is the array join function.